Isomorphic Free Groups Have Bijective Sets Using Category Theory
I'd like to prove that if $ X $ and $ Y $ are finite sets, $ F(X) $ and $ F(Y) $ are isomorphic as groups if and only if $ \lvert X \rvert = \lvert Y \rvert $.
This is relatively easy to prove without using category theory.
I'm wondering if there's a slick proof using category theory. I haven't been able to do it but I'm also new to category theory.

If something is easy to prove using elementary methods, what's the point of trying to prove it with more sophisticated methods?

@JeanAbouSamra I'm learning category theory and I'm trying to understand the limits of category theoretical arguments. Also, it seems to me that one of the best ways to learn category theory is to reinterpret what I've studied so far in category theoretic language.

I guess that the proof which I remember may be partially seen as category-theoretical (but this point of view hardly gives you any new information tbh). Exactly, you may consider the abelianization functor $\mathcal{Ab}\colon \mathsf{Grp}\to \mathbb{Z}-\mathsf{Mod}$ and prove that $\mathcal{Ab}(F(X))\simeq \mathcal{Ab}(F(Y))$ iff $|X|=|Y|$. This finishes the proof, because a functor must map isomorphic objects into isomorphic objects.

The "if" direction means that $F$ preserves isomorphisms, as all functors do. The "only if" directions means that $F$ is conservative (when restricted to finite sets), i.e. reflects isomorphisms.

@NaïmFavier No, a conservative functor is defined differently.

@JeanAbouSamra Using category theory for this is not sophisticated at all, it just gives the right perspective (look at homomorphisms) to solve this in one line without effort and even without invoking any deep result either. See my answer.

@MartinBrandenburg OK, I had in mind the proof reducing to linear algebra by abelianization, which is comparatively less sophisticated than category theory, but I recognize your proof is very nice.

@MartinBrandenburg oh yeah, I guess what I had in mind is rather "full on isomorphisms".

The "categorical" solution is to count homomorphisms to any non-trivial finite group. If $X$ has $n$ elements, then there are $2^n$ homomorphisms $F(X) \to C_2$ by the universal property of the free group. So we can recover $n$.
This is really at the heart of the philosophy of category theory: don't look at the internal structure of an object. Instead, look at the relations from the object to other objects.
We can also generalize this argument as follows.
Lemma. Let $U : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ be a functor* with a left adjoint $F$. Assume that there is an object $A \in \mathcal{C}$ such that the number of elements of $U(A)$ is finite and greater than $1$. Then,
$$F(X) \cong F(Y) \iff X \cong Y$$
holds for all finite sets $X,Y$.
*not necessarily a forgetful functor.
Proof. The direction $\Leftarrow$ holds for any functor. Now assume $F(X) \cong F(Y)$ holds. Write $a,x,y$ for the cardinalities of the sets $U(A),X,Y$. We have an isomorphism of sets
$$\hom(X,U(A)) \cong \hom(F(X),A) \cong \hom(F(Y),A) \cong \hom(Y,U(A))$$
which implies $a^x = a^y$. Since $a > 1$, this shows $x=y$, meaning $X \cong Y$.
In particular, we can apply this to free groups, free lattices, free commutative rings, free semigroups, etc.
By the way, the claim is also true for free $R$-modules for non-zero commutative $R$, but it might happen that every non-trivial $R$-module is infinite (for example when $R$ is an infinite field). But with filtered colimits it is possible to reduce to the case that $R$ is of finite type, and then some quotient is a finite field, and we win. The same trick works for free (commutative) $R$-algebras.

Maybe a stupid question. You assume $U$ be forgetful functor? But how come there is a free group with finitely many elements? Because you need a non-trivial free group which has finite elements.

That's super nice, thank you :)

@user11695417 I have clarified this in the answer.

That is nice. Thank you :)

Just a random remark (I know it doesn't apply because $X$ and $Y$ are assumed to be finite): If $x$ and $y$ are infinite, then the implication $a^x=a^y \Rightarrow x=y$ is undecidable in ZFC even for $a=2$, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17152/when-2-alpha-2-beta-implies-alpha-beta-alpha-beta-cardinals
